# Можно ли в bootstrap блоку задать ширину?

Tags: css, bootstrap

Как установить фиксированную ширину блока в bootstrap? 
Пробовал сделать так `<div class="col-md-1" style="width: 200px;">`, но безуспешно. Прошу помощи, кто знает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все работает:

```css
.fix {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  
  <div class="col-md-1 fix"></div>
```

для другой ширины (100px):

```css
.fix {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  
  <div class="col-md-1 fix"></div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]